# Setting different font URL in CSS file for development and production (Webpack)

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

This is how I'm embedding the Nunito font in my Chrome Extension:

**manifest.json:**

```
// more code
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "css": ["style.css"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
],
// more code
"web_accessible_resources": [
    {
        "resources": ["*.ttf"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
]
```

**style.css**:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/Nunito-Medium.ttf');
}
```

The font is successfully embedded when I compile my extension and load it in Chrome. However, when I'm developing the extension in `localhost`, I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

I think this happens because `localhost` can't interpret `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__`, so I have to change that path when I'm developing in `localhost`.

But as you can see up there, the path to the font is hard-coded in an CSS file (`style.css`). So I can't change the path. Is there any way around this?

Note: I'm using Webpack:

**package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack --watch --config webpack.dev.js",
  "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
},
```